# Create a String of all possible combinations of 4 digit numbers str = "0000", "0001", ..."9999"; - java

Tags: java, string

I need to create a string of all possible 4 digit combinations of numbers.
Like str= "0000", "0001", "0002", ..., "9999";

I can print out the combinations, but the task is to save this to a string, and I can't seem to find a solution. Here's the code that I've written so far. It works perfectly for the output.

```
public class AufgabeTrial {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for(int w=0; w<=9; w++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<=9; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<=9; y++)
            {
                for(int z=0; z<=9; z++)
                    
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(w) + String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(y)+ String.valueOf(z));
                    
                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save to the string"?

Comment: That would be a very long string.

Comment: What do you mean "it works perfectly for the output"?

Comment: You can do it like:``str+=String.valueOf(w) + String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(y)+ String.valueOf(z)+","``.

Comment: Btw, your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @khelwood - 10 possible values in 4 possible combinations is 10^4 (10k) unique combinations. Each substring is 4 chars long, so 40k chars. Not *that* bad...

Answer (score 5):

You can use String.format. Please see the following example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPattern();
      }
    
      private static void printPattern() {
        for (int i=0;i<=9999;i++){
          System.out.println(String.format("%04d", i));
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing them, you can append them to a `StringBuilder`. Once all the loops are finished you can get the desired string by calling `StringBuilder#toString`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int w = 0; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z <= 9; z++)
                        sb.append(String.valueOf(w) + String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(y) + String.valueOf(z))
                                .append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```